# XML is not being Parsed with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, xml, nsxmlparser

i'm trying to parse one simple XML file with NSXMLParser...here is my code..

```
    -(void) parseXml{        
        NSString *XmlPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myXML" ofType:@"xml"];         
        //NSLog(@"%@",XmlPath); path found!       

         NSData *xml=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:XmlPath];
         //NSLog(@"%@",Xml); outputs : xml in hexadecimal coded form   

        self.Xmlparser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xml];
        //NSLog(@"%@",self.Xmlparser); outputs : some hexadecimal code

        self.Xmlparser.delegate=self;

        NSLog(@"%@",self.Xmlparser);        

        if([self.Xmlparser parse])
            NSLog(@"PARSED");
        else
            NSLog(@"NotPARSED");
    }
```

OUTput is "NotPARSED" ... what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you can check that its parse or not in its delegate method are bellow..

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
    NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);

    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
     NSLog(@"NotPARSED");
}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
     NSLog(@"PARSED");
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        currentFilm       = [Film alloc];
        currentNodeContent =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: yes thanks..i used `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError` and getting alertView...how should i debug what is wrong!?

Comment: here not anything wrong dude just implement delegate method related of our class only..

Comment: it's done! ...was problem in my xml file...i validated it on http://validator.w3.org/check and solved errors!..now it's working..

Comment: do you know what self.Xmlparser should print? , im getting.. `3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e302220 656e636f 64696e67 3d225554 462d3822 3f3e0a0a 3c70656f 706c653e 0a202020 203c7065 72736f6e...` , should it be pure xml?